# Clarifications on signed/unsigned load and store instructions (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips, sign-extension, zero-extension

I can't seem to grasp the concept on these stuff, even with the help of Google and a textbook in my hand.

Following the format (opcode, rs, rt, offset)...

- Do you sign extend the offset before adding it to the value of the address? Or add before extending?
- In the case of **lb** and **lbu**, what's the difference? Does it also follow the MIPS arithmetic definition that 'unsigned' just means it won't report an overflow?
- Why doesn't **lw** have an unsigned version? Even the store instructions don't have one...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> In the case of `lb` and `lbu`, what's the difference?

The "load byte" instructions `lb` and `lbu` load a single byte into the right-most byte of a 32-bit register.  How do you set the upper 24 bits?  The *unsigned* operation will set them to zero; the signed operation will [sign-extend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) the loaded byte.

For example, suppose you read the byte `0xFF` from memory.  `lbu` will 0-extend this value to `0x000000FF` and interpret it as 255, while `lb` will sign-extend it to `0xFFFFFFFF`, which is interpreted as -1.

> Why doesn't `lw` have an unsigned version? Even the store instructions don't have one...

The "load word" instruction (`lw`), on the other hand, loads a 32-bit quantity into a 32-bit register, so there is no ambiguity, and no need to have a special signed version.

If you are storing less than a full 32-bit word, there is nothing you can do with the extra bits in the register except throw them away (ignore them).

> Does it also follow the MIPS arithmetic definition that 'unsigned' just means it won't report an overflow?

I think this convention is only for the add and subtract instructions.  For the other instructions, signed/unsigned indicates whether sign-extension will be performed.

> Do you sign extend the offset before adding it to the value of the address? Or add before extending?

If an offset is sign-extended, it only makes sense to do it before adding it to the base address.  I think a review of [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) arithmetic will make this clear.

Comment: What about save byte `sb`? Is the byte sign-extended or zero-extended before storing?

Comment: @NoName: Since it's store __*byte*__, I think it should be zero-extended or one will store *more* information than one mean to. (good question btw)

Comment: @Kindred: not really, store byte has neither zero-extension or signed-extension. By definition, it only stores the rightmost byte in the register to 1 byte of the memory, leaving other bytes untempered.